# Hadoop data and control flow

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, control-flow, dataflow

I'm writing a Hadoop application but it seems that I have misinterpreted how exactly hadoop works. My Input files are tiles of a map, named according to the [QuadTile](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/QuadTiles) principle. I need to subsample those, and stitch those together until I have a certain higher-level tile which covers a larger area but at a lower resolution. Like zooming out in google maps.

One of the things I have done is that I have written a mapper which executes on every (unsplittable) tile like this:

```
public void map(Text keyT, ImageWritable value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

     String key = keyT.toString();

    //check whether file needs to be processed
     if(key.startsWith(context.getJobName(), 0)){

         String newKey = key.substring(0, key.length()-1);
         ImageWritable iw = subSample(value);
         char region = key.charAt(key.length()-1);
         iw.setRegion(region);
         context.write(new Text(newKey), iw);
     }else{
         //tile not needed in calculation
     }
 }
```

My reducer looks like this:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<ImageWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    ImageWritable higherLevelTile = new ImageWritable();
    int i = 0;
    for(ImageWritable s : values){
        int width = s.getWidth();
        int height = s.getHeight();
        char c = Character.toUpperCase(s.getRegion());
        int basex=0, basey=0;
        if(c=='A'){
            basex = basey = 0;
        }else if(c=='B'){
            basex = width;
            basey = 0;
        }else if(c=='C'){
            basex = 0;
            basey = height;             
        }else{
            basex = width;
            basey = height;
        }

        BufferedImage toDraw = s.getBufferedImage();
        Graphics g = higherLevelTile.getBufferedImage().getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(toDraw, basex, basey, null);
    }               
    context.write(key, higherLevelTile);

}
```

As you maybe can derive from my code I expected hadoop to execute in the following way:
1) Map all tiles of level one
2) Do a first reduce. here I expected the Iterable values to have four elements: the four subsampled tiles of the lower level.
3) Map al tiles currently in context
4) reduce all tiles in context. Again, Iterable values will have 4 elements...
5) ... repeat...
6) when no more maps left -> write output

Turns out, that is not correct. My reducer is called after every Map, and Iterable never seems to have more than one element. I tried to fix that by altering the reducer code a bit by assuming Iterable would have 2 elements: one subsampled value, and one partially finished higher-level tile. Turns out, that is not correct either.

Can anyone tell me, or point me towards, how the flow of hadoop actually is? What should I do to make my use-case work? I hope I explained it clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is right that all of the maps complete before the first reduce starts. That is because each reduce is guaranteed to get its input in sorted order and the last map to finish may produce the first key for all of the reduces.

Each map produces its output, a pluggable interface called the partitioner picks the reduce that should receive each key. The default uses `key.hashCode() % num_reduces`, because that gives good distribution in the normal case. That might be your problem since there is no requirement `"A"`, `"AB"`, and `"ABC"` will go to the same reduce.

Finally, each of the reduces is called once for each of its keys. The iterator goes through the values that were associated with the same key. Note that the values are generally unsorted, but that can be controlled with the secondary sort.

Take a look at: http://riccomini.name/posts/hadoop/2009-11-13-sort-reducer-input-value-hadoop/ .

If you want an example of secondary sort, I wrote one and put it in the Hadoop examples. http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/examples/SecondarySort.java

Comment: You say that all maps finish before the first reduce starts. But in my current code, that is running in single node mode, they really dont...  Could it be that a reduce is performed after an input file is completely mapped? Since my tiles are unsplittable, a first reduce will happen after every map task? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Ah, I see that in my driver code the combinerclass was set to my reducer, probably some copied code which i completely forgot about. I commented out that code and now a reduce only happens after all maps completed. Right now I need to iterate the map and reduce operations until only a certain key is left which should be the tile  that was asked for. I will start up a new question for that. Thanks for your answer.